# DependencyObject for AppMenu in silverlight application

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone

I am creating an appmenu in windows phone silverlight 8.1 using ApplicationBarIconButton and ApplicationBarMenuItem through code. But how do I set AutomationProperties.SetName() through code  for this appmenu. What would be the depedendencyObject that I should pass to AutomationProperties.SetName() ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post some actual code you need help with :-) For more information how to ask see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi derape , i am stuck with setting AutomationProperties.Name for AppMenu. And in that i am not able to use any dependencyObject to set AutomationProperties.Name . The Code base i am talking about is kind of big. Please let me know if anything specific is needed, i'll post that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use AutomationProperties.Name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920062/how-to-use-automationproperties-name)